# Extracting integer from a number

Tags: javascript

I recently purchase Javascript the Goods Parts by Douglas Crockford. I was going through the Augmenting Types section and I needed some help in the following code concept.

```
Number.method("integer", function(){
  return Math[this < 0 ? "ceiling" : "floor"] (this);
});

document.writeIn((-10/3).integer());
```

According to the book the result should be 3 but I am getting an error while I did console.log instead of document.writeIn.

Number.method is not a function. Being a javascript beginner, I am a bit confused, any help would be appreciated.

Thank You. 
Udit G.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868883/augmenting-types-in-javascript (check it)

Comment: Sorry but I did search before posting. But thanks, I will follow up on that page now.

Comment: Hope the findings there will help you out with your question :)

Answer (score 5):

he defined the function "method" on another occasion. it is not part of the standard.

an example is here http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html#sugar

```js
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

you just should tie it to Object or Number instead of Function as in the link.

Comment: I am still a lil confuse. So what you mean is I shouldn't follow that technique of coding ?

Comment: You may use it, but keep in mind that it is only a shortcut (and imo not an overly useful one). There is quite some discussion around whether one should extend the native objects or use some own namespace.

Comment: Alright Thank you for the suggestion. I will do a bit more research on Augmenting Types.